# In the last function "largest", "Initializing 'double' with an expression of incompatible type 'double [10]'"

Tags: c, function, variables

In the last function "largest", I am trying to print the largest number by comparing the 2 doubles but it does not let me assign it to a variable and gives me an error "Initializing 'double' with an expression of incompatible type 'double [10]'". I am not sure what the issue is and how I would find the player with the highest score.

```
#define MAX 10

// Main struct
struct players{
    char name[20];
    double score[MAX][MAX];
};

// function declaration
int playerName(struct players *test);
int playerScore(struct players *test, int nop);
double largest(struct players *test, int nof, int nop);

int main(void) {
    int i,j;
    int nop, nof;
    struct players mainPlayers[MAX];

    nop = playerName(mainPlayers);
    nof = playerScore(mainPlayers, nop);
    for (i = 0; i < nop; i++) {
        printf("%s ",mainPlayers[i].name);
        for (j = 0; j < nof; j++) {
            printf("%.2lf ",*mainPlayers[i].score[j]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

// gets players name
int playerName(struct players *test){

    int i;
    int nop = 0;

    printf("Enter Number of players: ");
    scanf("%d", &nop);

    for (i = 0 ; i<nop; i++) {
        printf("Enter player %d's name: ", i+1);
        scanf("%s", test[i].name);
    }
    return nop;
}

// gets players score
int playerScore(struct players *test, int nop){
    int i,j;
    int nof = 0;

    printf("Enter Number of fields: ");
    scanf("%d", &nof);

    for (i = 0 ; i<nop; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < nof; j++) {
            printf("Enter player %s's score %d: ", test[i].name, j+1);
            scanf("%lf", test[i].score[j]);
        }
    }
    return nof;
}

// supposed to get the largest score out of all the scores and print that players name and score in the main function.
float largest(struct players *test, int nof, int nop){

    int i,j;
    double largest = test[i].score[j];
    for (i = 0; i < nop; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < nof; j++) {
            if (test[i].score[j] < test[i].score[j+1]) {
                largest = test[i].score[j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best to limit the scope of variables therefore, suggest removing the statements like:

```
int i,j;
```

and, in each `for()` loop replacing expressions like:

```
for (i = 0; i < nop; i++)
```

with:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < nop; i++ )
```

and similarly for each of the `for()` loops

in function: `largest()`  regarding:

```
int i,j;
double largest = test[i].score[j];
```

The local variables `i` and `j` are being used without having been initialized to any specific value.  The result is undefined behavior.

regarding:

```
for (j = 0; j < nof; j++) {
        if (test[i].score[j] < test[i].score[j+1])
```

since the local variable `j` increments to the max valid index for the array, the expression: `test[i].score[j+1]` will be accessing beyond the end of the array.  Remember: the valid indexes into any array (in C) are 0...(number of elements in array -1)

regarding:

```
scanf("%s", test[i].name);
```

this `%s` will allow the user to enter more than 19 characters.  The result of such action by the user results in a buffer overflow and undefined behavior.  Should also be checking the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  Suggest:

```
if( scanf("%19s", test[i].name) != 1 )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "scanf for player %d name failed\n", i );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```

Where 19 is because the field `name[]` is 20 characters long and `%s` always appends a NUL byte to the input.

in function: `largest()` regarding:

double largest = test[i].score[j];

Since the variables `i` and `j` are not initialized, this is undefined behavior.  suggest using:

```
double largest = 0.0;
```

and moving that line to immediately after:

```
for (i = 0; i < nop; i++) {
```

so it is 'reset' for each new player that is being evaluated

Now for your problem:

regarding:

```
float largest(struct players *test, int nof, int nop){
    ....
double largest = test[i].score[j];
```

Do not use the name of the function as a local variable within that function.  The compiler sees that as a 'recursive' call rather than as a local variable.

Suggest using an unique name for the local variable.

Answer (score 0):

In your definition of player:

```
struct players{
    char name[20];
    double score[MAX][MAX];
};
```

Each player has a name, and also has a 2-dimensional grid of 100 scores.

I don't know what kind of game this is meant to represent, but typically, a single player has a single score.   Why did you give each player a big matrix of 100 scores?

Comment: (New to programming ) Each player has multiple scores. Therefore I had to make a 2d array to score every players multiple scores. Any improvements are welcome

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 10

// Main struct
struct players{
    char name[20];
    double score[MAX][MAX];
};

// function declaration
int playerName(struct players *test);
int playerScore(struct players *test, int nop);
double largest(struct players *test, int nof, int nop);
void ppg(struct players *test, int nof, int nop);

int main(void) {
    int nop, nof;
    struct players mainPlayers[MAX] = { 0 };

    nop = playerName(mainPlayers);
    printf("\n");
    nof = playerScore(mainPlayers, nop);
    printf("\n");
    ppg(mainPlayers, nof, nop);

    return 0;
}

// gets players name
int playerName(struct players *test){

    int i;
    int nop = 0;

    printf("Enter Number of players: ");
    scanf("%d", &nop);

    for (i = 0 ; i<nop; i++) {
        printf("Enter player %d's name: ", i+1);
        scanf("%s", test[i].name);
    }
    return nop;
}

// gets players score
int playerScore(struct players *test, int nop){
    int i,j;
    int nof = 0;

    printf("Enter Number of fields: ");
    scanf("%d", &nof);

    for (i = 0 ; i<nop; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < nof; j++) {
            printf("Enter player %s's score %d: ", test[i].name, j+1);
            scanf("%lf", &test->score[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return nof;
}

// finds the largest number (Did not use)
double largest(struct players *test, int nof, int nop){

    int i = 0,j = 0;
    double largest2 = test->score[i][j];
    for (i = 0; i < nop; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < nof; j++) {
            if (test->score[i][j] > test->score[i][j+1] && test->score[i][j+1] != '\0') {
                largest2 = test->score[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    return largest2;
}

// Calculates and prints the player name and their ppg
void ppg(struct players *test, int nof, int nop){

    double sum = 0;
    int div = 0;
    double ppg = 0;
    char *name = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i<nop; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<nof; j++) {
            if (test->score[i][j] == 0) {
                div++;
            }
            sum+= test->score[i][j];
        }
        sum/= (nof-div);
        if (ppg < sum) {
            ppg = sum;
            name = test[i].name;
        }
        sum = 0;
        div = 0;
    }
    printf("%s had the highest ppg with %.2lf points\n", name, ppg);
}
```